# How to hide a bar if Value is null?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

How to remove the empty gap on the chart if chart value is Null (or 0)?

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/x13o8Lgj/

You can see empty space on the "Mon 21 Oct". How to remove the  white gap?

```
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Toyota'],
      ['Mon 19 Oct', 4, 8, 3],
      ['Mon 20 Oct', 11, 4, 7],
      ['Mon 21 Oct', 6, null,6],
      ['Mon 22 Oct', 10, 5,2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Statistics',
        subtitle: 'Car',
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature is not supported but you could consider the following solution for remove the empty gap in bar group. 
The idea is to move the remaining  bars in group to fill the gap between them.

> Note: Every bar is rendered in Google Chart as a `path` element. In
>   the provided example it is supported to fill the gap for group
>   consisting of 3 bars.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["bar"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Toyota'],
      ['Mon 19 Oct', 6, null, 8],
      ['Mon 20 Oct', 11, 5, 7],
      ['Mon 21 Oct', 6, 6,null],
      ['Mon 22 Oct', 4, 5, 2]
    ]);

    

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Statistics',
            subtitle: 'Car',
        },
    };
    
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        configureBarOptions(chart,data);
    });
    chart.draw(data, options);
}


function configureBarOptions(chart,data){
    
    var chartDiv = chart.getContainer();
    var bars = chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('path');
    if(bars.length == 0)
      return;


    var w = bars[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var numOfEmptyBars = 0;
    forEach(data,function(row,col,val){
          if(val == null || val == 0){
               var pos = ((data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) * row) + col - 1 - numOfEmptyBars; 
               if(col == 1) { /* first empty bar in group? */
                  bars[pos].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(-' + w/2 + ', 0)');
                  bars[pos+1].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(-' + w/2 + ', 0)'); 
                  numOfEmptyBars++;
               } 
               else if (col == 2) { /* middle empty bar in group? */
                  bars[pos-1].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + w/2 + ', 0)');
                  bars[pos].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(-' + w/2 + ', 0)');
                  numOfEmptyBars++;
               }  
               else { /*last empty bar in series? */
                  bars[pos-1].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + w/2 + ', 0)');
                  bars[pos-2].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + w/2 + ', 0)');
                  numOfEmptyBars++;
               }
          }
    });
    


    
}


function forEach(data,func){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); j++){
            var val = data.getValue(i,j);   
            func(i,j,val);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```